# pip command not working at all when installing python modules

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I tried installing the discord module, but it gave me quite an odd error.

Upon:

```
pip install discord
```

Command prompt simply gives me:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am on inactivated Windows if that is relevant.

Comment: T[his should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487831/unable-to-use-pygame-in-vscode/70487955#:~:text=I%20had%20this,affect%20the%20installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 1):

Try `python pip install module`.
Other things to try if all else fails:

```
python -m pip install module

python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org module
```

Answer (score 0):

I too received the same issue, Please ensure (if you are using windows) that you have installed the correct windows version.

the file name of the python will be as follows, the version number may vary.

> python-3.9.8-amd64.exe